# MySQL-It cannot be hosted, even though the application runs smoothly on localhost

Tags: mysql

Why does this code produce an error when hosted, and when fixed, there are non-functioning features?
Help me please

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Functions
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `kode_automatis` (`kode` INT) RETURNS CHAR(7) CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci  BEGIN
DECLARE kodebaru CHAR(7);
DECLARE urut INT;
 
SET urut = IF(kode IS NULL, 1, kode + 1);
SET kodebaru = CONCAT("TRX", LPAD(urut, 4, 0));
 
RETURN kodebaru;
END;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `kode_automatis2` (`kode` INT) RETURNS CHAR(7) CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci  BEGIN
DECLARE kodebaru CHAR(7);
DECLARE urut INT;
 
SET urut = IF(kode IS NULL, 1, kode + 1);
SET kodebaru = CONCAT("TRF", LPAD(urut, 4, 0));
 
RETURN kodebaru;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

There are no errors occurring, and all features are functioning properly.

Comment: What error? What features? This question is super thin on context.

Comment: The `DELIMITER` keyword is used in MySQL command-line client and tools like MySQL Workbench to handle statements that contain semicolons. If you are running this script in an environment that doesn't recognize DELIMITER (like PHP's mysqli), it may cause a syntax error... . But you need to provide more context

Comment: Error
SQL query:


--
-- Functions
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `kode_automatis` (`kode` INT) RETURNS CHAR(7) CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci  BEGIN
DECLARE kodebaru CHAR(7);
DECLARE urut INT;
 
SET urut = IF(kode IS NULL, 1, kode + 1);
SET kodebaru = CONCAT("TRX", LPAD(urut, 4, 0));
 
RETURN kodebaru;
END
MySQL said: Documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user 'if0_34573995'@'192.168.%' to database 'if0_34573995_db_keuangan'

Comment: How is this question related to PHP?

Comment: What's the difference between "hosted" and "fixed"? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase "hosted" presumably means running on a commercial web hosting service, rather that on the local PC.

Comment: @SyahrulNizam The error message tells you exactly what the problem is: the user running the script doesn't have appropriate grants to define a function.